# Troubleshooting faulty electric oven

Tags: electrical, oven, power

My electric oven is exhibiting the following symptoms:

- Oven not heating up at all
- Grill (Broil in American English?) not heating up at all
- Fan is working OK
- Power light doesn't come on, nor the light next to the temperature dial (that indicates the oven is yet to reach the selected temperature)
- Light bulb inside the oven doesn't come on

The first thing I noticed was the light bulb inside the oven wasn't on whilst I was cooking, but the oven was working OK. But then the next day, it doesn't heat up at all or appear to be turning on at all (except the fan).

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot the problem? I would be nice to find the fault before calling out an engineer.

Make and model is: Bush AE6BFS

Comment: There could be many things wrong. Almost impossible to debug through the internet. Get the professional in to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: What is the make and model?

Comment: When you say Grill not heating is this the stove top ? the oven section is a common failure of a relay that dammages the control board on electrolux ovens, we do need the make and model to point you in the correct direction

Comment: @EdBeal It would seem "grill" is British English, and the American term is "broil" (I think?)

Comment: @Tester101 Have updated the original question with make and model. It's a store own-brand make and model, but may perhaps just be re-badged from a more well known make (or a generic Chinese model)

Comment: found a parts list the only user book I could find had no schematics. http://www.partmaster.co.uk/cooker-oven/ae6bfs-5400157560/catalogue.pl?shop=bush&path=592111&model_ref=2595974&page=9 I need to learn how to make the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the oven tested by a professional and the cause was the function control switch[1], which the knob is connected to. Looks like a connection inside of it had broken due to wear and tear. It's been replaced and the oven is now functioning as normal

[1] http://www.partmaster.co.uk/cooker-oven/ae6bfs-5400157560/oven-function-selector-switch/product.pl?pid=3262627&shop=bush&path=592111&refine=function+selector+switch&model_ref=2595974

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with the terminal block (located just inside where the power cord enters the oven wall), the power cord or the electrical supply. To check the terminal block: unplug or disconnect at the breaker panel, remove the cover plate (usually in the back) to expose the terminal block. Look for any evidence of a problem: terminals discolored or black, melted wire insulation, etc. Check and test the power cord next. attach a jumper wire to two of the terminals that the power cord are connected too. Next, with a continuity tester (or DVM) clip a test lead to the two prongs of the plug (make sure the prongs are the ones that have been jumped at the block). There should be continuity, but wriggle the prongs to find an intermittent or loss connection. If light (or reading) of the tester fluctuates while moving the prongs than plug is damaged and should be replaced.